# run time error using datediff and between

Tags: sql, date, runtime, datediff, between

I'm new to SQL and I'm facing the following issue
I'm using this:

```
DATEDIFF(day, Date1, Date2) between -31 and 0
```

after a where statement as part of my code and I'm running into time error issues. Seems like the code is running and after a certain time it stops

Does any of you ever use datediff and between as above?
What I need is to filter cases where the difference between these two dates are greater than -31 but also negative.
If there is another way I'm happy to use it

Both dates are in datetime format.

Comment: (1) What database are you using (please tag appropriately)?  (2) What are the data types of `Date1` and `Date2`?  Or, more importantly, why are you storing them as strings and not as proper dates.

Comment: `and after a certain time it stops` ... can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Which database it is?

Comment: `I'm running into time error issues` like a timeout? how much time it takes for your query to finish? Can you toss in whole code?

Comment: both date1 & date2 are in datetime format. Also it takes around 4 minutes to run and then the query is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
DATEDIFF(day, Date1, Date2) between -31 and 0
```

is correct.  The only run-time error I can think of would occur if `Date1` and/or `Date2` are stored as *strings* rather than dates.  You should use appropriate types for data -- and the appropriate type for a `date` is `date`.

You should fix the data.  But you can get around this by doing:

```
DATEDIFF(day, TRY_CONVERT(date, Date1), TRY_CONVERT(date, Date2)) BETWEEN -31 AND 0
```